# Qunit - Assert the arguments of a function are valid

Tags: qunit

**Problem:**
I am trying to check whether the arguments of a function are valid in terms of type and whether they're defined/null to make sure the arguments aren't going to cause issues. I would then want to push different values to these arguments to test the outcomes are as expected.d

**Questions**

What's the best way to do this in QUnit?

**What I've tried**

Not much, can't seem to get the arguments of a function as an option for QUnit functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with ease using [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org).

An quick example:

```
var spy = sinon.spy();
functionWithCallback( spy );

ok(
  spy.calledWithMatch( sinon.match.object, sinon.match.array ),
  "will be called with object and array"
);
```